# What city am I in?

Tags: wordplay, rebus

**What City Am I in?**  
There's something with a

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the name of the city looks like *___ican___*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it

> **River City, Iowa** from the musical *The Music Man*.

The pictures may represent

> the lyric: "Ya got trouble, folks, right here in River City. Trouble with a **capital "T"** And that **rhymes** with **"P"** and that stands for **pool**!

Comment: Amazing! One of my favorites too :)

Answer (score 0):

> Tempe, AZ : starts with Capital 'T' sounds like 'Pee'... 
>  Antelope, CA : 'An T lobe pee'... 
>  Taipei, Taiwan : 'T' sounds like 'Pee'

They're all a stretch.

> The 'T' in front of the capital building reminds me of the ASL sign for 'potty'.

Answer (score 0):

The last image could maybe represent

> people (pee + pool)?

But I can't figure out what the first two mean...

> The first image seems to be the US Capitol building with the ASL sign for "T" laid over it, but "Tapitol" isn't a word...